# How can I use another script from a script?

Tags: unity, c#

The first script is very long, and I need to use only the top of it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class mBitmap2MeshV30a : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Texture2D SourceTexture; 
    private float Pixel_vs_Unit_Scale = 1;  
    public float extrudeDepth = 1; 
    private Vector2 scanpoint;
    private bool gotStart = false;
    private int maxsteps = 512; 
    public bool invertFaces = false;
    private Mesh srcMesh;
    private mMeshExtrusion2.Edge[] precomputedEdges;
    private List<ExtrudedTrailSectionBM3> sections;

    public class ExtrudedTrailSectionBM3
    {
        public Vector3 point;
        public Matrix4x4 matrix;
        public float time;
    }
```

I need to assign a value to `SourceTexture` from another script. This is the other script:

```
void Start ()
{
    text2d = new Texture2D(10, 10, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
    System.Drawing.Font myf = new System.Drawing.Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 12);
    Image myimage =  DrawText("Hello", myf, System.Drawing.Color.Red, System.Drawing.Color.Black);
    Bitmap mybitmap = new Bitmap(myimage);

    MemoryStream msFinger = new MemoryStream();
    mybitmap.Save(msFinger, mybitmap.RawFormat);

    text2d.LoadImage(msFinger.ToArray());
    filter.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = text2d;

    mBitmap2MeshV30a bb = new mBitmap2MeshV30a();
    bb.SourceTexture = text2d;
}
```

The problem is I can't make a new `mBitmap2MeshV30a bb = new mBitmap2MeshV30a();`. Both scripts are attached to the same GameObject, in the hierarchy.

Comment: You don't construct `MonoBehaviours` with `new`. Are you looking for `GetComponent` to access an existing component, or `AddComponent` to attach a new component?

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing this `mBitmap2MeshV30a bb = new mBitmap2MeshV30a();` make that class [singleton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx).

to create any class as [singleton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) you nees to make an static instance of that class by `public static mBitmap2MeshV30a instance` after creating instance you can provide the instance value to object by providing `instance=this` in `void Awake()` after providing instance you can call any function by `mBitmap2MeshV30a.instance.SourceTexture`.